# How to use information_schema and get the count of procedures containing the word “sum”?

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

How to use the `information_schema` to get the count of procedures containing the word “sum”?

I wanted to know the query using the performance schema.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for information_schema.routines contains all the procedures and it is trivial to pick out those with sum in the name but with your reference to performance schema I think I must be missing something.

Comment: can you give example and what is your expectation?

Comment: i want a select query for all the procedures having the word "sum" using information schema.........?

Comment: Are you after routine_definitions in information_schema.routines for procedures containing the word 'sum' or those containing the aggregation function SUM()?